# Present modal from NSWindowController without using Storyboards

Tags: swift, xib, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I building a macOS framework that's running at the beginning of the login process and I want to show some information to the user in a window. I have an NSWindowController with a .XIB file and it's the main window for my framework.

I would like to add more presentAsSheet to another view. For that, I created an NSViewController with a .XIB to define the user interface that an I want to present in a modal but here I'm completely blocked because getting the contentViewController of the window its always nil

I'm initializing my main window like this:

```
func run() {
  NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
  mainWC = MainWC(windowNibName: "MainWC")
  guard mainWC.window != nil else {
    return
  }
  NSApp.runModal(for: mainWC.window!)
}
```

Where Im trying to present the other NSViewController"

```
self.window?.contentViewController?.presentAsSheet(customViewController)
```

In my MainWindowController I'm doing this:

```
@IBAction func btnAction(_ sender: Any) {
  let customModal = CustomModal(windowNibName: "CustomModal")
  self.window?.beginSheet(customModal.window!, completionHandler: { code in
    print(message: "Clicked")
  })
}
```

The modal never appears

Answer (score 0):

You can't present the view until the window and the content view have been loaded

Either inside the window controller in `windowDidLoad()`

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()
    // present the view
}
```

or even in `viewDidLoad` of the view controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // present the view
}
```

Comment: @AlexGonzalez Wondering if you have solved this issue. I am facing a similar issue. I am building an authorization plugin for macOS. I am not able to load a NSViewController inside a NSWindow.

Comment: @iBuilt Did you find any solution?

Comment: @AlexGonzalez Yes I did. I was initializing the ViewController inside a method. I made the ViewController object a global variable in the class and initialized it in the  viewDidLoad method and it worked perfectly.